# why does model.find return [ ]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, find

I want to get some object form **Ad table**.
I tried:

```
Ad.find(:all, :conditions => {:header => "1"})
```

and:

```
Ad.find(:all, :conditions => ["header=?", "1"])
```

but return a empty array.
when i try `Ad.all` I see Objects which match to my conditions

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Rails 3.0, you should be using the new Arel syntax:

```
Ad.where(:header => "1")
```

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and http://asciicasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3 for more info

Comment: you mean with something like Mongoid or MongoMapper? You should clearly state it in the question.